# ipsec vpn with preshared key p

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, ipsec

I understood that three session keys are generated by diffi-helmen and nonces, in phase 1 msg 3 and msg 4 both exchanged diffi-helmen public key and generate shared secret key ,and shared secret key and nonces are mixed together to created three session keys ,
1 encryption key 
2 authentication key
3 derivate key

now i want to know that what is sent in msg 5 msg 6 ,and how pre-shared key encrypted and how both verify each other authentication with pre-shared key

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

All of your questions were already answered in [your original question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13468/in-ipsec-vpn-how-pre-shared-key-is-encrypted/13473#13473).

> In Main Mode, the Pre-Shared-Key (PSK) is verified in Messages 5 and 6.  Message 5 and 6 are Protected by the Session keys ISAKMP generates, described above.
>
> In Aggressive Mode, none of the messages in the negotiation are encrypted.  And the PSK is verified in Messages 2 and 3.  Notice, I said in both cases the PSK is *verified*, and I never said the PSK is *exchanged*.  Obviously, if nothing in Aggressive mode is Encrypted, and you simply sent the Pre-Shared-Key across the wire unencrypted, there would be a huge gaping security vulnerability.
>
> Lucky for us, the writers of ISAKMP already thought of that.  And as a result, they created a special method for verifying that each party has the correct PSK, without actually sharing it across the wire.  There are two items that are use to validate to each Peer that they both have the same PSK:  the **Identity Method** and the **Identity Hash**.
>
> VPN Peers can choose to identify themselves by various methods; most commonly, peers will simply use their source IP address.  But they have the option to use a FQDN or Hostname.  Each of these, along with the correlating value for the chosen method, are what make up the Identity Method.  So for example, if I had the IP 5.5.5.5, and I wanted to use my IP address to identify myself, my **ID Method** would effectively be **[IP Address, 5.5.5.5]**.  *(Note:  BOTH values make up the entire ID Method)*
>
> The ID Method is then combined (using a PRF) with the Seed value we discussed earlier (SKEYID), and a few other values, to create the **Identity Hash**.   Recall, that what went into creating SKEYID in the first place was the Pre-Shared-Key.
>
> The ID Method and ID Hash are then sent across the wire, and the other party attempts to re-create the ID Hash using the same formula.  If the receiver is able to re-create the same ID Hash, it proves to the receiver that the sender must have had the correct pre-shared-key.

and

> When doing a pre-shared key authentication, Main Mode is defined as
>     follows:
>
> ```
>          Initiator                        Responder
>         ----------                       -----------
>          HDR, SA             -->
>                              <--    HDR, SA
>          HDR, KE, Ni         -->
>                              <--    HDR, KE, Nr
>          HDR*, IDii, HASH_I  -->
>                              <--    HDR*, IDir, HASH_R
> ```

Message 5 is HDR, IDii, and HASH_I
Message 6 is HRD, IDir, and HASH_R

In my description, IDix was the ID Method, and HASH_x was the ID Hash.  Was there something in there that didn't make sense?

---

If Firewall1 has the IP 1.1.1.1, and Firewall2 has the IP 2.2.2.2, and they are both using the Pre-Shared-Key of "Zebra", then Message 5 and Message 6 would include this information:

```
1.1.1.1                                    2.2.2.2
----------                             -----------
HDR*, IDii, HASH_I   ---5-->
                     <--6---    HDR*, IDir, HASH_R
```

Message 5 would include:

- IDii, which is effectively **[IP Address, 1.1.1.1]**.
- HASH_I, which is a hash of the following values:  (**SEED Value** + IDii + Public Values)

Message 6 would include:

- IDir, which is effectively **[IP Address, 2.2.2.2]**
- HASH_R, which is a hash of the following values:  (**SEED Value** + IDir + Public Values)

The *Public Values* above are values that were exchanged in cleartext Messages 1, 2, 3, and 4, that anyone would have access to if they were eavesdropping on the wire.  The Seed Value is the only part of the Hash that would only be known to whomever had the original Pre-Shared-Key.  As one of the values that went into creating the Seed Value is the string "*Zebra*" -- aka, the pre-shared-key.  See above, and [the original answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13468/in-ipsec-vpn-how-pre-shared-key-is-encrypted/13473#13473) for more details on how that is formed.

Comment: What that means that msg 5 and msg 6 are protected by session keys,how can id method be same on both sides , if its not then how other peer will create the same hash

Comment: Both sides have different IPs, therefore they each have a different ID Method value.  I edited my answer and gave an example.

Comment: please dont mind , i have studied alot about vpn but it seems that u have grate knowledge of vpn i just want you to just have a look at that

Comment: please dont mind . i have studied alot about vpn but it seems u have a grate knowledge about vpn ,i just want u to have a look on that how much i understood

Comment: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13551/ipsec-vpn-with-pre-shared-key