# Site to Site VPN Theory

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, cisco-ios

So basically ive been configuring a ton of site-to-site VPN's previously, but i have never got the theory behind it 100% straight..
Youtube is filled with videos on how to configure a site-to-site connection, that is obviously no issue but i'm looking for a video or text that describes the different phases and possibilities.. Like what is Phase 1 and Phase 2, and what kind of encryptions and algorithm are available and why exactly do we prefer to use one over another?
All the configuration videoes out there basically just tells you to use this and this because its the best, it never compares the different possibilites and goes further in depth.

Does anyone know a video or tutorial on this without having to read or view additional 3 hours footage of stuff i already know before getting to the point?

Comment: I'm actually in the process of putting together a rather comprehensive series of blog posts together that cover this exactly, precisely because I didn't find a good 'single stop' resource online that outlined it all in one place. In the mean time, there is some good information in [this question](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13468) and [this question](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13495) which might satisfy a part of your curiosity.

Comment: Product or resource recommendations are specifically off-topic.

Comment: putting this on hold because 'resource recom' are off-topic. But you could just tweak the wording a bit to make it ask for a high-level outline of how VPNs work (and probably even better if you specify a VPN type/product, eg, IPSEC)

Answer (score 0):

The sample chapter on "VPNs and VPN Technology" from the Cisco Press book "Cisco Secure Virtual Private Networks" is a pretty good summary of IPSec VPNs and how all the bits and pieces fit together. You can find it here: http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=24833