# IKE phase 1 and phase 2

Tags: vpn, ipsec, authentication, ike

Was going through the IKE phase 1 and phase 2. I have some questions regarding the same which is bothering me with respect to main mode and quick mode.Please correct me if i go wrong somewhere.

**Phase 1 Main Mode**:

1)The 1st and 2nd packets are transfer of SA proposals and cookies.

Question:Arent the cookies generated by hashing the senders IP, port , protocol and timestamp? If thats the case, does the receiver need the algorithm used to calculate the hash so that he can confirm the data or is it just a random value which the receiver does not have to be bothered by.

2)The 3rd and 4th packets exchange the **Diffie Hellman public key and nonces** and a **shared secret** is generated to again calculate additional 3 keys.

Question: The Nonces are combined with **psk** to generate a **seed value** . So how and when does **PSK** gets exchanged. Is it communicated outside of these packet exchanges or are part of these packets.

3)After the seed value is calculated, it is combined with the shared secret to generate additional 3 keys to **authenticate, encrypt and use as a keying material** to generate keys for Phase 2.

Question: These keys are used to authenticate and encrypt the packets which are used in phase 2 by the algorithms(authentication and encryption) negotiated in Phase 1(packets 1 and 2)right?
And also to encypt and authenticate the 5th and 6th packets of Phase 1.

So what exactly are we transferring in packets 5th and 6th to authenticate and encrypt them?
And are all the 3 session keys claculated by both Initiator and responder?
And are those 3 keys(Authentication, encryption and derivative keys) symmetric?

**I have gone through the RFCs and many other documents but cant find the answers to these questions**. I know these may be silly ones, but please help me figuring out if Im understanding it all wrong or not.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are looking into the deprecated IKEv1? And not the simpler and more modern IKEv2 ([RFC 7296](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7296))?

Comment: Yes. Im learning IKEv1 for a certification In Security and also want to learn how it worked.. So when i was reading through this topic, above questions popped up and Im unable to get the answers and unable to move forward. So please help me if you have any answers for these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good questions.

> 1)The 1st and 2nd packets are transfer of SA proposals and cookies.
>
> Question:Arent the cookies generated by hashing the senders IP, port ,
> protocol and timestamp? If thats the case, does the receiver need the
> algorithm used to calculate the hash so that he can confirm the data
> or is it just a random value which the receiver does not have to be
> bothered by.

The cookie's are arbitrarily generated (often randomly). They are 64 bits from the Initiator and 64 bits from the Responder, and collectively (the 128 bits) serve as the identification of a particular ISAKMP "tunnel" (or ISAKMP "SA") -- i.e., a particular set of the 3 ISAKMP keys (encryption, authentication, derivative).

*(much like SPI's will identify a particular IPsec SA / tunnel)*

The values are also used within the calculation of the 3 ISAKMP keys, but that doesn't happen until after message 3 and 4, so the Initiator and Responder will have already agreed upon the necessary hashing algorithms.

> 2)The 3rd and 4th packets exchange the Diffie Hellman public key and
> nonces and a shared secret is generated to again calculate additional
> 3 keys.
>
> Question: The Nonces are combined with psk to generate a seed value .
> So how and when does PSK gets exchanged. Is it communicated outside of
> these packet exchanges or are part of these packets.

The PSK is "exchanged" between the peers before the tunnel has ever tried to build. Theoretically via phone call or manually configuring the PSK on both sides.

Both parties are *verified to have the proper PSK* in Messages 5 and 6. What goes into creating the E/A/D ISAKMP keys is the PSK, so if both parties didn't start with the correct PSK, they could never create the same E/A/D keys, and would not be able to "understand" each other's message 5 and 6.

> 3)After the seed value is calculated, it is combined with the shared
> secret to generate additional 3 keys to authenticate, encrypt and use
> as a keying material to generate keys for Phase 2.
>
> Question: These keys are used to authenticate and encrypt the packets
> which are used in phase 2 by the algorithms(authentication and
> encryption) negotiated in Phase 1(packets 1 and 2)right? And also to
> encypt and authenticate the 5th and 6th packets of Phase 1.

Yes. After Messages 1-4 of Main Mode, three ISAKMP Keys exist:  Encryption Key, Authentication Key, Derivative Key.

The Encryption Key and Authentication Key will secure Messages 5 and 6 of Main Mode, and any ensuing Quick Mode negotiation messages.

The Derivative Key is not used by ISAKMP, it is instead given to IPsec so IPsec can generate its own Encryption and Authentication Keys.

> So what exactly are we transferring in packets 5th and 6th to authenticate and encrypt them?

*What* is exchanged is somewhat arbitrary, the *why* is what is important. The purpose of Messages 5/6 are to validate the other party is who they claim to be (aka, the other party has the correct pre-shared-key).

Here is *(some of)* what goes into calculating the value that is exchanged in message 5 and 6, and more importantly the purpose it serves:

- Pre-Shared-Key -- a value which can only be known by the intended recipients in the conversation
- [Diffie-Hellman](https://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/cryptography/diffie-hellman/) Shared Secret -- a value which can only be known by the two parties who exchanged messages 3/4
- Arbitrary Data -- values exchanged in Messages 1-4 which tie this particular authentication attempt to this particular conversation (preventing replying a previous connection's authentication attempts)

There are two parts to the Arbitrary Data, one set is from the Initiator and the other set is from the Responder. So in the end, you have two collective values exchanged in Messages 5 and 6:

- PSK / DH Shared Secret / Arbitrary Initiator Data
- PSK / DH Shared Secret / Arbitrary Responder Data

Both the Initiator and Responder have the information they need to put together *both* values above. Therefore, *both* Initiator and Responder have a value they can use to prove *they* are who they say they are, and a value they can use to verify *the other* is who they say they are.

The specific details are outlined on [Page 10 of RFC 2409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2409#page-10). I also explain some of the details of the process in [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13468/in-ipsec-vpn-how-is-the-pre-shared-key-encrypted/13473#13473).

> And are all the 3 session keys claculated by both Initiator and responder?
> And are those 3 keys(Authentication, encryption and derivative keys) symmetric?

Yes and Yes.

And in Main Mode they protect the Exchange of the identity values described above in Message 5 and 6.

Comment: This post has helped me a lot in understanding the concepts in more depth. Appreciate it.

Comment: @RRHS Glad it helped. Definitely check out [the other answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13468/in-ipsec-vpn-how-is-the-pre-shared-key-encrypted/13473#13473) -- it has more details as to how the PSK is validated and what happens in messages 5 and 6.

Answer (score 2):

**ISAKMP/IKEv1 is deprecated and should not be used anymore, it was replaced by IKEv2.**

> Arent the cookies generated by hashing the senders IP, port , protocol and timestamp?

It's open to implementations how they generate the cookies (or SPIs as they're called in IKEv2). [RFC 2408, section 2.5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2408#section-2.5.3) describes some possibilities (but e.g. strongSwan 5.x just generates random SPIs).

> If thats the case, does the receiver need the algorithm used to calculate the hash so that he can confirm the data or is it just a random value which the receiver does not have to be bothered by.

The recipient can't verify the cookie value provided by the peer.  But that's not the point, which is that the cookie value that was *sent to* the peer can be verified later when handling inbound messages.

> The Nonces are combined with psk to generate a seed value . So how and when does PSK gets exchanged. Is it communicated outside of these packet exchanges or are part of these packets.

The PSK is never exchanged over IKE. As the name suggests (*Pre-Shared* Key), it must be shared and configured before establishing the connection.

> So what exactly are we transferring in packets 5th and 6th to authenticate and encrypt them? And are all the 3 session keys claculated by both Initiator and responder? And are those 3 keys(Authentication, encryption and derivative keys) symmetric?

Yes, these keys are symmetric and calculated by both peers. Messages 5 and 6 are encrypted with the established encryption key (`SKEYID_e`) and the `HASH_I|R`/`SIG_I|R` payloads to authenticate the IKE SA are generated using the generated shared base key (`SKEYID`). The authentication key (`SKEYID_a`) is only used to authenticate Phase 2 messages (Quick Mode, Informational) via `HASH(1..3)` payloads (these messages are encrypted with `SKEYID_e` too, though). More details can be found in [RFC 2409, section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2409#section-5).

Comment: Understood. Just needed some level of understanding before i start with IKEv2. Thanks