# How SKEYID_a in IKEV1 phase 1 used in authentication in message 5 and 6?

Tags: ipsec, ike

How SKEYID_a in IKEV1 phase 1 used in authentication in message 5 and 6 ?

Comment: Have you read [RFC 2409](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2409)?

Comment: These two questions are relevant, possibly duplicates of your question:  [IKE phase 1 and phase 2](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/55421/3675) and [In IPsec VPN, how is the pre-shared key encrypted?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/13473/3675)

Comment: Actually I have already gone through both Links and that was very useful but still I am not clear about how SKEYID_a be useful in Phase 1 Message 5 & 6 Exchange .

Comment: Hello Zac67 , I tried to go through RFC as well but that create more confusion like is they used only for ISAKMP Notify Payload or an ISAKMP Delete Payload not actually in Message 5 and 6 exchange.